# Connecting to multiple messaging systems in spring cloud stream application using configuration class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have got a requirement to read all the `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder` from a cloud configuration service. I was able to move the bindings to separate configuration class by defining a `@BindingServiceProperties` bean. Also was able to move one Kafka system properties to a configuration class by defining a `@KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties`. If both the Kafka server properties are moved in as binder configuration, the application is unable to identify the binder and respective bindings. Need help in defining **multiple binders** in a configuration class and attach each binders to respective bindings.

application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      defaultBinder: kafka1
      binders:
        kafka1:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
              brokers: localhost:9095
              autoCreateTopics: true
              configuration:
                auto.offset.reset: latest
        kafka2:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
              brokers: localhost:9096
              autoCreateTopics: true
              configuration:
                auto.offset.reset: latest
```

Using the application.yml configuration I'm able to attach the binder to respective bindings.

BinderConfiguration

```
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public BindingServiceProperties bindingServiceProperties() {
        BindingServiceProperties bindingServiceProperties = new BindingServiceProperties();

        BindingProperties input1BindingProps = getInput1BindingProperties();
        BindingProperties input2BindingProps = getInput2BindingProperties();

        Map<String, BindingProperties> bindingProperties = new HashMap<>();
        bindingProperties.put(StreamBindings.INPUT_1, input1BindingProps);
        bindingProperties.put(StreamBindings.INPUT_2, input2BindingProps);
        bindingServiceProperties.setBindings(bindingProperties);

        return bindingServiceProperties;
    }

    private BindingProperties getInput1BindingProperties() {
        ConsumerProperties consumerProperties = new ConsumerProperties();
        consumerProperties.setMaxAttempts(1);
        consumerProperties.setDefaultRetryable(false);

        BindingProperties props = new BindingProperties();
        props.setDestination("test1");
        props.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        props.setGroup("test-group");
        props.setConsumer(consumerProperties);
        props.setBinder("kafka1");
        return props;
    }

    private BindingProperties getInput2BindingProperties() {
        ConsumerProperties consumerProperties = new ConsumerProperties();
        consumerProperties.setMaxAttempts(1);
        consumerProperties.setDefaultRetryable(false);

        BindingProperties props = new BindingProperties();
        props.setDestination("test2");
        props.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        props.setGroup("test-group");
        props.setConsumer(consumerProperties);
        props.setBinder("kafka2");
        return props;
    }
```

KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties

```
    @Bean
    public KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties getKafka1BinderProps(){
        KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties
                = new KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties(new KafkaProperties());

        String brokers = "localhost:9095";
        kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties.setBrokers(brokers);
        kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties.setDefaultBrokerPort("9095");
        Map<String, String> configuration = new HashMap<>();
        configuration.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties.setConfiguration(configuration);

        return kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties getKafka2BinderProps(){
        KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties
                = new KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties(new KafkaProperties());

        String brokers = "localhost:9096";
        kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties.setBrokers(brokers);
        kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties.setDefaultBrokerPort("9096");
        Map<String, String> configuration = new HashMap<>();
        configuration.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties.setConfiguration(configuration);

        return kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties;
    }
```

Application is working fine with the properties defined in application.yml without moving binder configuration into separate configuration class.

Complete code can be found in [this](https://github.com/VinodhSubramanian1193/scs-multibinder-kafka) repository.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you running into any issues? Did you get a chance to take a look at these samples? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/multi-binder-samples.

Comment: All of those samples are working applications. Take a look at the two Kafka clusters sample. I think that is similar to your use case.

Comment: The application is working fine with the application.yml configuration. But i want to move the binder configuration from yml file to some configuration class where i can assign the broker values from any cloud configuration service at application start

Comment: If u can see above, I've already moved the binding properties to a configuration file from application.yml.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. If you are trying to assign broker values dynamically at startup, why don't you use some place holder templates like this? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/multi-binder-samples/multi-binder-two-kafka-clusters/src/main/resources/application.yml#L30

Comment: Then when your app starts, you can pass the respective values.

Comment: Thanks for the response @sobychacko. But the requirement is to read it from a custom cloud-config server, and we have restriction to not provide anything in the application.properties or as environment variable or arguments. So I've found a way to configure one Kafka cluster in an atypical way, have trouble in configuring multiple Kafka clusters.